# Deletion in Binary search tree in java

Tags: binary-search-tree

Why am I not able to delete the desired node ?. For example if I construct a tree with entries in this order 1,2,3,4,5 and use my delete method to delete 3 then the nodes containing 3 and less will be deleted instead of only 3 and I shall get 4,5 if I again print all the nodes in preorder.Please help.

import java.util.Scanner;

class tnode {

```
protected int data;

protected tnode left,right;

public tnode(){

    data=0;

    right=left=null;

}
public tnode(int v){

    data=v;

    right=left=null;
}

public int getdata(){

    return data;
}

public tnode getleft(){

    return left;
}

public tnode getright(){

    return right;
}
```

}
class btree{

```
protected tnode root;

public btree(){

    root=null;
}

public boolean isEmpty(){

    return root==null;
}

public void insert(int val){

    root=insert(root,val);
}

private tnode insert(tnode r,int val){

    if(r==null){

        r=new tnode(val);
    }

    else{

        if(val>r.getdata()){

            r.right=insert(r.right,val);
        }

        else{

            r.left=insert(r.left,val);
        }
    }

    return r;
}
public void preorder(){

    preorder(root);
}

private void preorder(tnode r){

    if(r!=null){

        System.out.print(r.getdata()+" ");

        preorder(r.getleft());

        preorder(r.getright());
    }
}

public int min(){

    return min(root);

}

public int min(tnode r){

    if(r.left==null){

        return r.getdata();

    }

    else{

        return min(r.left);

    }

}

public void delete(int val){

    root=delete(root,val);

}

private tnode delete(tnode r,int val){

    if(r==null){

        return null;

    }

    else if( val>r.getdata()){

        r=delete(r.right,val);

    }

    else if(val<r.getdata()){

        r=delete(r.left,val);

    }

    else{// when r.data=value

        //if node has both children

        if(r.left!=null && r.right!=null){

            tnode temp=r;

            //get the minimum value in right sub tree

            int min_right=min(temp.right);

            //replace this with the node to be deleted

            r.data=min_right;

            //delete this node

            r=delete(r.right,min_right);

        }

        //if has left child

        else if(r.left!=null){

            r=r.left;

        }

        //if has right child

        else if(r.right!=null){

            r=r.right;

        }

        else{

            //if has no child

            r=null;

        }

    }

    return r;

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
private tnode delete(tnode r,int val){

if(r==null){

    return null;

}

else if( val>r.getdata()){

    r=delete(r.right,val);  //it should be r.right=delete(r.right,val);

}

else if(val<r.getdata()){

    r=delete(r.left,val);  //it should be r.left=delete(r.left,val);

}

else{// when r.data=value

    //if node has both children

    if(r.left!=null && r.right!=null){

        tnode temp=r;

        //get the minimum value in right sub tree

        int min_right=min(temp.right);

        //replace this with the node to be deleted

        r.data=min_right;

        //delete this node

        r.right=delete(r.right,min_right);

    }

    //if has left child

    else if(r.left!=null){

        r=r.left;

    }

    //if has right child

    else if(r.right!=null){

        r=r.right;

    }

    else{

        //if has no child

        r=null;

    }

}

return r;
```

}